# Sniffing WiFi using monitor mode long-term and decrypting

Tags: wifi, sniffing

So I wanted to sniff packets in my WiFi network. To capture them all I use monitor mode (as suggested in my previous question) . I know I can decrypt traffic using key by setting it in the wireshark options but I want to sniff for month or longer to do some analysis. I decided to use tshark or dumpcap but I don't know how to sniff and decipher the traffic in the same time without gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like

```
tshark -nr input.pcap -o wlan.enable_decryption:TRUE -o "uat:80211_keys:\"wpa-pwd\",\" Passphrase:SSID\""
```